# Varnish: Is it possible to not cache only one specific part of the page?

Tags: http, varnish

Let's say I have page at `example.com/location` - now I want the content of that URL to be cached, except only one specific HTML-part of the page, which should be updated regularly. This HTML-area should not land in the cache and the backend should instead be queried each time a request comes in for that part. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Yes, by not including that particular part in the actual page at all but by using jquery  load() or similar  to insert it from an external resource (file/script/URL)  and creating a different caching policy for that resource

Comment: Could you provide some example or more details?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19527586/1068283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You're after [ESI includes](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/esi.html).

That is, your `/location` code has to be rewritten to split cache-able / not cache-able stuff, e.g.:

```php
<?php
echo 'Hello, I will be cached';
?>
<esi:include src="/your-uncacheable.php"/>
```

Obviously, you'll put the logic for generating HTML that is not to be cached into the `/your-uncacheable.php`.

Then you will enable ESI in VCL:

```php
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.url == "/location") {
       set beresp.do_esi = true; // Do ESI processing
       set beresp.ttl = 24 h;    // Sets the TTL on the HTML above
    } elseif (bereq.url == "/your-uncacheable.php") {
       set beresp.ttl = 0m;      // Sets zero TTL on
                                 // the included object
    }
}
```